Find the second and third highest value per group excluding ties using SAS SQL
I am trying to find the highest, second highest, and third highest value per year and group. But if there are ties then the first/second highest could be the same, ect. like the example below:
have:
Year   Group   ID    Value
2000    A      001     103
2000    A      002     108
2000    A      003     108
2000    A      004      94
2000    B      005      87
2000    B      006      87
2000    C      009      89
2001    A      001      201
2001    B      005      302
2001    B      006      211
2001    B      007      211
2001    B      008      198
2001    C      009      277
2001    C      0010     246


want:
YEAR    GROUP  TOP_VALUE  NUM2_VALUE  NUM3_VALUE
2000     A       108         108        103
2000     B        87          87         NA
2000     C        89          NA         NA 
2001     A        201         NA         NA 
2001     B        302         211        211
2001     C        277         246        NA 

I can't find a solution that handles ties this way. Thanks in advance for any help!

Why would you use SQL when you can just use PROC RANK?

Because I don't know how lol

You can just SORT the dataset.
First let's convert your listing into an actual dataset.
data have;
  input Year Group $ ID $ Value ;
cards;
2000    A      001     103
2000    A      002     108
2000    A      003     108
2000    A      004      94
2000    B      005      87
2000    B      006      87
2000    C      009      89
2001    A      001      201
2001    B      005      302
2001    B      006      211
2001    B      007      211
2001    B      008      198
2001    C      009      277
2001    C      010     246
;

So if you just sort it then you can easily see the highest values.
proc sort data=have;
  by year group descending value;
run;

Result:

If you need that transposed to your wide format then use PROC TRANSPOSE.
proc transpose data=have out=wide(drop=_name_) prefix=value;
  by year group;
  var value;
run;

Result:

If you don't want those extra variables beyond the first three values then add a KEEP= dataset option.
proc transpose data=have prefix=value
  out=wide(drop=_name_ keep=year group value1-value3) 
;
  by year group;
  var value;
run;

